# Is there a way to limit the number of seps when doing read.table?

Tags: r

I have a piece of text data that I want to preprocess,
and this data is in the form of:

```
[num|num|<String>]
```

However, there are spaces, commas, and `"|"` in the <String>.
So, it is not possible to separate the data using `"|"`.
How could I implement the limit the number of divisions, or readlines when retrieving data?
I tried using `flush = TRUE`, but it can't be used because it erases some part of the <String>.

Comment: Use `readLines` to read the data and regular expression to separate the columns? It's difficult to propose a solution without seeing an example. If some of the text is going missing, it could mean that there are characters that are not recognized.

Comment: Re *"seps"*: Do you mean *"[steps](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/steps#Noun)"*?

Comment: for seps, I ment separate in  read.table(), like sep = ","

Comment: So, *[separators](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/separator#Noun)*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have something like this.

```
123|1234|foo, bar | baz
021|3874|foo, bar | baz
123|1234|foo, bar | baz
123|1234|foo, bar | baz
```

You could use a lookbehind, if there's a number `(?<=\\d)` before the `"|"`.

```
readLines('tmp.txt') |>
  strsplit('(?<=\\d)\\|', perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "123"            "1234"           "foo, bar | baz"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "021"            "3874"           "foo, bar | baz"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "123"            "1234"           "foo, bar | baz"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "123"            "1234"           "foo, bar | baz"
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
write(file='tmp.txt',
'123|1234|foo, bar | baz
021|3874|foo, bar | baz
123|1234|foo, bar | baz
123|1234|foo, bar | baz'
)
```

Comment: Nice trick of using `strsplit`, upvoted!

Comment: Oh my god. Your prediction is correct.
I have the data in the same shape as you mentioned.
This problem gave me quite a headache, but your idea really helped a lot.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The following similar idea is from [jay.sf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70576558/12158757) (and borrows data from there as well):

```
read.table(
  text = gsub(
    "(?<=\\d)\\|", "\t",
    readLines("tmp.txt"),
    perl = TRUE
  ),
  sep = "\t"
)
```

which gives

```
   V1   V2             V3
1 123 1234 foo, bar | baz
2  21 3874 foo, bar | baz
3 123 1234 foo, bar | baz
4 123 1234 foo, bar | baz
```